# Como creo un backup en PostgreSQL con .batch

Tags: postgresql, batch

Tengo un bat que crea el backup de una BD en PostgreSQL. Este es el codigo del batch:

```
@echo off 
SET PG_BIN="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\pg_dump.exe"
SET PG_HOST=localhost
SET PG_PORT=5432
SET PG_DATABASE=CELAUSystem
SET PG_USER=postgres
SET PG_PASSWORD=7777
SET PG_PATH=C:\Program Files\CELAUSystem
SET PG_FECHA=%date:~11,4%%date:~8,2%%date:~5,2%
SET PG_FILENAME="%PG_PATH%\%PG_DATABASE%_%PG_FECHA%.dump"
%PG_BIN% -U %PG_USER% -v -F c %PG_DATABASE% > %PG_FILENAME%
```

el resultado es este:

> "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\pg_dump.exe" -U postgres -v -F c CELAUSystem > C:\Program Files\CELAUSystem\CELAUSystem_20180710.dump

Funciona bien pero cuando se ejecuta el bat me pide que digite la contraseña del usuario de la BD y no crea el backup hasta que lo digite, como puedo hacer para que se digite automáticamente?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Nadie me contesto, pero encontré la solución, la explicare por si le ayuda a alguien en un futuro.
En el Batch, cuando se busca el archivo pg_dump se le escribe la contraseña de esta forma:

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\PGPASSWORD="7777" pg_dump.exe
>   Eso hará que ya no pida la contraseña.

Answer (score 0):

Antes

```
SET PG_PASSWORD=7777
```

debe ser

```
SET PGPASSWORD=7777
```

de esta forma el archivo **bat** ya no te pide la contraseña.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas... después de 4 años y 6 meses entro al post a hacer una pregunta, ojala haya respuesta jeje, quiero hacer lo mismo un archivo .bat para poder automatizar el backup de una base de datos en pgAdmin4, uso tu codigo, claramente usando mis datos y no me funciona, solo abre el cmd por 1 milisegundo y lo cierra sin hacer nada... alguna sugerencia?
Saludos

Comment: Hola, aunque lleves 4 años y 6 meses en el sitio te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer [answer] ya que esto no responde a la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/373569)